# Apache Rewrite (mod_rewrite) cannot rewrite, if directory name is same as another directory under root, such as “lib”, on Linux

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-16.04

I have a website running on Ubuntu 16.04.3 on Amazon EC2. Here is the result of `uname -a`

```
Linux ip-172-31-34-232 4.4.0-1050-aws #59-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 30 19:57:10 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The root directory of my website is:

```
/var/www/html/www
```

So there is such a line in my 000-default.conf:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www
```

I have a directory named `lib` in the root directory. The full path of the directory is:

```
/var/www/html/www/lib
```

There are some css and js files in it. For example:

```
/var/www/html/www/lib/customized.css
```

There was no problem at all, until I started to use Apache Rewrite (mod_rewrite).

If I don’t write any rewrite rule, it is fine. `lib/customized.css` can be accessed from `http://hostname/lib/customized.css` with HTTP status code 200, which means everything is OK.

If I rewrite for other directories, it is fine. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^\/img\/.*$ $0 [L]
```

After writing the line above, I can still access anything under `img`. For example, I could access `img/logo.png` from `http://hostname/img/logo.png`.

However, if I want to do the same thing for `lib`, either adding:

```
RewriteRule ^\/lib\/.*$ $0 [L]
```

or changing the existing line to

```
RewriteRule ^\/(img|lib)\/.*$ $0 [L]
```

Everything under `lib` becomes inaccessible. I will get:

```
403 Forbidden
```

for anything under `lib` (full path: `/var/www/html/www/lib`).

This seem to happen **only** for directories named `lib` directly under the document root directory. If I create a symlink pointing to `lib` but named `lib2`, and write this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^\/lib(\/.*)$ /lib2/$1 [L]
```

or, if I create a symlink pointing to `../lib` in `img` and still named `lib`, and write this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^\/lib(\/.*)$ /img/lib/$1 [L]
```

Everything works like a charm. No 403. Only 200.

To make it worse, this bug **does not exist on Windows <s>or Raspbian on Raspberry Pi Zero W</s>** (see UPDATE 3). I tested my rewrite rules on both Windows <s>and Raspberry Pi Zero W</s> (see UPDATE 3) before uploading them to Amazon EC2, just to find this weird bug.

I’ve also checked the `error.log`, and found this for accessible case (files under `img`, unrelated info omitted):

```
[rid#7fc9349cc0a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /img/logo.png
[rid#7fc9349cc0a0/initial] applying pattern '^\\/(img|lib)\\/.*$' to uri '/img/logo.png'
[rid#7fc9349cc0a0/initial] rewrite '/img/logo.png' -> '/img/logo.png'
[rid#7fc9349cc0a0/initial] local path result: /img/logo.png
[rid#7fc9349cc0a0/initial] prefixed with document_root to /var/www/html/www/img/logo.png
[rid#7fc9349cc0a0/initial] go-ahead with /var/www/html/www/img/logo.png [OK]
```

And, this for inaccessible case (files under `lib`, unrelated info omitted):

```
[rid#7fc9349ce0a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /lib/zenscroll-4.0.0/zenscroll-min.js
[rid#7fc9349ce0a0/initial] applying pattern '^\\/(img|lib)\\/.*$' to uri '/lib/zenscroll-4.0.0/zenscroll-min.js'
[rid#7fc9349ce0a0/initial] rewrite '/lib/zenscroll-4.0.0/zenscroll-min.js' -> '/lib/zenscroll-4.0.0/zenscroll-min.js'
[rid#7fc9349ce0a0/initial] local path result: /lib/zenscroll-4.0.0/zenscroll-min.js
[rid#7fc9349ce0a0/initial] go-ahead with /lib/zenscroll-4.0.0/zenscroll-min.js [OK]
[rid#7fc9349ca790/initial/redir#1] init rewrite engine with requested uri /error.php
...
... (error.php is a customized ErrorDocument, omitted)
...
[authz_core:error] [pid 13179] [client 61.149.87.39:57002] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /lib/zenscroll-4.0.0
```

It seems that, `mod_rewrite` failed to prefix with document_root, if the directory is having a same name as another directory under the root directory. For my case, it is `lib` having the same name as `/lib`.

So I created a directory named `img` under the root directory, thus `/img`, and boom! Files under `img` (full path: `/var/www/html/www/img`) became inaccessible, too!

My current solution is to create a link under `/var/www/html/www` named `lib2` and rewrite like this:

```
RewriteRule ^\/lib(\/.*)$ /lib2/$1 [L]
```

I don’t want to rename the `lib` directory, because everything works well on both Windows <s>and Raspbian</s> (see UPDATE 3). Is there any other solution? For example, can I:

1. <s>Update the apache on Ubuntu to a newer version that solved this bug</s> (not working, see UPDATE 1), or
2. Tell the apache that they should prefix before actually trying to access `/lib`?

Apache on Ubuntu (version number seems to be a bit outdated, but I don’t know how to upgrade to versions newer than what Ubuntu provides):

```
Package: apache2
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: httpd
Installed-Size: 489
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5
```

Apache on Raspbian:

```
Package: apache2
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: httpd
Installed-Size: 577
Maintainer: Debian Apache Maintainers <debian-apache@lists.debian.org>
Architecture: armhf
Version: 2.4.25-3+deb9u3
```

Apache on Windows:

```
AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  9 2017 11:48:22
```

## UPDATE 1

Updated Apache to 2.4.29 via ppa:ondrej/apache2 but no luck. It is still having the same issue that Windows <s>and Raspbian</s> (see UPDATE 3) do not have.

```
Package: apache2
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: httpd
Installed-Size: 504
Maintainer: Debian Apache Maintainers <debian-apache@lists.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 2.4.29-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2
```

## UPDATE 2

There are such lines in apache2.conf:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>
```

I thought `/lib` was denied because it was a part of `/`, so I modified it to:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and restarted Apache2. Still no luck. 403 Forbidden.

## UPDATE 3

Re-checked Raspbian. Same issue occurred on Raspbian with Raspbian Pi Zero W.

Probably it was OK due to browser cache. My bad. Now I think this is not an bug specific to Ubuntu, but specific to Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The target (or substitution string) in a RewriteRule is assumed to be a file path, by default. The use of the [PT] flag causes it to be treated as a URI instead.
>
> from: [RewriteRule Flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt)

By default, the rewrite target is assumed to be a file path first (absolute path) before a URI (relative path to DocumentRoot). Therefore, the final solution, is to use [PT] flag in rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^\/(img|lib)\/.*$ $0 [PT]
```

and it works now!

[L] is no longer necessary, because [PT] implies [L].